# No sound on Ubuntu/Windows dual-boot

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, sound

**TL;DR**: Booting into Ubuntu after first booting into Windows disables sound on Ubuntu (dual-boot Ubuntu 16.04 LTS/Windows 10)

Recently I decided to try Linux, so I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS as a dual-boot option to already installed Windows 10 on my laptop. But I found out no sound is coming out of my speakers when using Ubuntu (sound works fine on Windows).

So I've tried [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure) guide, and found out step #1C helped (**it installed some updates**). I later restarted and switched to Windows. As I later switched back to Ubuntu, no sound was coming out of speakers again so I tried the same as before (step #1C), but now it didn't solve the problem (**no updates were installed as the system was up to date**).

I later tried modifying alsa-base.conf file as pointed out [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1606078/comments/5), but it also didn't help.

Somewhere on the Internet I read that the issue could be caused by Windows Fast Boot. I tried to cold restart (holding power button for ~5 sec) laptop and log into Ubuntu first, and now the sound worked. So I switched to Windows and disabled Fast Boot in power options. Then I switched back to Ubuntu but the sound was not working again. I tried cold restarting again and switched between Ubuntu and Windows but the issue remains same. Booting into Ubuntu after first booting into Windows disables sound on Ubuntu.

**NOTE**: Pulseaudio shows speakers are not muted

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This problem occurs after booting into a different OS than previously.

Just put the computer to sleep and wake it up, and the problem is solved, the sound comes back. Works both ways round for Windows and Ubuntu

However this problem seems to be fixed in the new ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Could you please explain what is the cause?

Comment: I do not know. But it works. I asked about it at windows support and they did not know it either.

Comment: I've been trying to solve another problem (flat sound on linux) and somehow the no sound problem disappeared. Unfortunately I don't know which of the 'solutions' for flat sound solved no sound.

Comment: I am experiencing this in Ubuntu 18.04, and suspending fixed it. Hotkeys for sound do not work however, while hotkeys for screen brightness does. Details: I was listening to Foo Fighters.

Comment: Solved my problem. Thank you. [Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, dual windows 10]. Didn't expect it would work.

Answer (score 1):

Waking from sleep didn't resolve my issue.  But this did:

1. Log into Windows
2. Go to Device Drivers
3. Find Intel Audio Driver
4. If it has a warning flag next to it, update driver.

Worked immediately after the update completed.

Comment: Updating the drivers worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a work around, not a fix: Boot into Win10. At login window click restart and boot in to Linux Distro. Will have sound. Unfortunately,  always do this for Linux sound.

Looks like Win10 does not release Conexant sound driver for direct boot to Linux.

Comment: There's easier workaround, just put laptop to sleep then wake it up and sound works again.

Comment: Suspend on linux mint did not work, boot into win 11 and restart at the login window worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same boat as you, I followed the instructions in [this guide](https://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/) and it worked great.  Specifically:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio

sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio

sudo alsa force-reload
```

Comment: I've tried the same, but it didn't help. Only thing that solves the problem so far is putting the laptop to sleep, then waking it up.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when dual boot ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10 in ASUS UX433F. Then I updated the kernel version to 4.19.10. After that it started working!

```
$ sudo ukuu --install v4.19.10
```

If ukuu is not installed you can install by

```
$ sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:teejee2008/ppa
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install ukuu
```

After installing ukuu open a new terminal install the new version of ubuntu kernel.

**References:** 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1784485/comments/78
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1784485

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have Window 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 on my Asus notebook. There is a failed Bios upgrade when I checked in Window update. Retry the upgrade and sound works again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the dual boot of Ubuntu 16.4 and Windows 10 on my Dell PC. But the fix was easy for me -- simply searched for **Applications > System settings > Sound** and found that the Output volume was set at minimum. After dialing the bar to ~ 80%, sound came alive. Rebooted the PC and it's still working. Looks like the initial setting of the built-in audio controller requires an adjustment.

[image: Sound settings toolbar]

```
user@bud:~$ sudo lshw -class sound
  *-multimedia            
       description: Audio device
       product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1b
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
       version: 04
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
       resources: irq:28 memory:e1a60000-e1a63fff
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue on dual-boot Ubuntu 18( and 19)/Windows 10. It starts after launching Windows 10 a few times. The sound was playing for a few seconds and then had disappeared.
I solved it by disabling Windows 10 fast startup. https://help.uaudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/213195423-How-To-Disable-Fast-Startup-in-Windows-10

Answer (score 0):

I am using an HP Spectre x360 and I had this same problem (with both 16.04 and 18.04). The "put it to sleep and wake it up" method worked for me, but I also looked for a more permanent fix.

I found it, as a cut-and-paste edit to the GRUB file: `/etc/default/grub`

[No audio with newest model HP Spectre x360 (4101-dx)](https://askubuntu.com/q/655135/925513)

After running `sudo update-grub` I did have to reboot twice for it to work.

I don't know if this is only for HP or the Spectre x360, but the sound card is Realtek, so hopefully this will work as a permanent fix for other people as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have an Asus laptop.  The fix for me was to:

1. Shut down Windows
2. Unplug the power
3. Boot up Linux
4. When I am in the desktop and confirm that audio and wifi are working, I plug the power back in.

Comment: Yes, we need to *power off* laptop to make sound works again in Linux