# Ubuntu 18.04 Built in Audio no longer working

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

I tried using hooking my laptop up to an external display through HDMI and now the built in audio does not work. I can still get audio through the audio jack. pavucontrol shows that audio should be playing through the built in speakers. I have tried reinstalling ALSA but that didn't work. My computer recognizes my soundcard, but still nothing plays. I tried updating drivers and got this error

W:Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://miktex.org/download/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386', E:The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.

I have a Razer Blade 2017 with Ubuntu 18.04 installed. Any suggestions?

edit:
I dual boot with Windows 10 and the audio works fine there.

edit:
I have found a non ideal solution. If I put my laptop into suspend and then log back in, audio works fine. Still have no idea what the root of the problem is though.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/a/1165640/968501

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Twice. I tried everything. Read every thread. Uninstalled/reinstalled everything.

I don't remember what exactly fixed the problem, but it was either one or a combination of these simple things:

1. Plugged the laptop back into the HDMI port, and then unplugged it.
2. System settings > Sound > Choose the correct output (e.g. "Speakers - Built-in Audio").

Comment: I saw some threads and forum posts that said that worked for people. Also adding things to /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf. Unfortunately none of those worked in my case. It looks like there was a similar problem for 16.04 though according to this thread https://askubuntu.com/questions/955065/no-sound-on-ubuntu-windows-dual-boot.

Comment: If you plug your laptop back into the same HDMI in, do you get sound through the TV/monitor/whatever it may be?

Comment: When I was first having the issue, I got no sound whatsoever, even through the monitor. Now when I try, I get sound through my computer's built in speakers.

Comment: So when your laptop is plugged into the HDMI device, you get no sound anywhere?

Comment: Yes, originally that was the case. Now my computer plays the audio through the built in speakers as opposed to the ones the monitor is connected to.

Answer (score -1):

I dual boot windows as well, and just solved it on my machine twice.

The issue seems to arise when switching from Win10 back to Ubuntu.

For me simply entering BIOS fixed the problem both times.
I did NOT change any settings, but when I booted back into Ubuntu the audio was working again.

Hope this helps!

edit:

Just as a note. My issue was that my built-in audio (my laptop's speaker) was not working. So according to your responses, it might be a different issue.