# No sound playing on Asus laptop Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: sound, alsa, asus

I have a relatively new Asus Zenbook UM433 dual booted with Windows. It's been working fine for a few months but the sound has suddenly stopped working. I upgraded and updated everything and it worked for a while but has stopped again. No sound plays through speakers or headphones. It has no errors, for instance:

`aplay -D plughw:1,0 /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav`

Appears to be playing the sound, but nothing is heard.

I have dutifully gone through every step of this guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure
but nothing has worked.

Here is the output asked for in Step 3: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/4ZB4CzWSsP/

And here is the output for Step 5: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/VKtwbxW6Cz/

I'm sure it's something simple that I've missed. I'd appreciate any suggestions!

Thanks in advance

Edit: The sound works fine in windows so the hardware is obviously ok.

Comment: that is, you boot Win - sound works, reboot to Ubuntu - no sound?

Comment: That's correct, the sound is fine in windows

Comment: did you see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/955065/no-sound-on-ubuntu-windows-dual-boot)?

Comment: I had a look, thanks. Unfortunately none of the fixes mentioned there worked. I tried disabling fast boot, the "sleep and wake up" method, purging and reinstalling alsa and pulseaudio, editing alsa-base.conf etc. None of these or the other suggestions worked.