# Speakers and Headphones Fail in Dual-Boot Laptop with Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS but Work Fine on Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, sound

**Story:**

When I first dual booted the laptop everything was great for the first few months. Then I discovered the extra amplification that Ubuntu provides, and really cranked up the volume. A week or two later my speakers were garbled and dropped all sound after a few seconds. I assumed I'd blown out the speakers, so I ordered replacements from ASUS. I was using Ubuntu as my daily driver so I didn't check at this time what they were doing in Windows. Replacement speakers behaved exactly the same as previous speakers within a few hours of install. I discovered at this point that the sound worked perfectly in Windows. I tested headphones and they work great in Windows, but behave exactly the same as the laptop speakers in Ubuntu: garbled while cutting in-and-out for about 3-5 seconds before dropping off completely. I've since been trying different solutions, but mostly wound up back on Windows for other reasons, so I haven't bothered to find a resolution yet... but I cannot figure this out, and would love some input.

**TL;DR:**

Dual-booted laptop used Ubuntu's over-amplification, speakers when to shit. Replaced speakers, no change. Tried headphones, they are garbled like speakers. Windows sound works great.

**ASUS ZenBook Specs:**

- Intel Core i7-10510U
- 16GB RAM
- 512GB PCIe SSD
- GeForce GTX 1650
- Replaced Speakers with official OEM ASUS speakers

**Attempted Solutions:**

- Check that I'm not being stupid and have the correct source for audio output (Confirmed because it works for a few seconds)
- Installed Volume Control for Pulseaudio

  > sudo apt install pavucontrol
- Checked alsa mixer
- Reloaded alsa

  > sudo alsa force-reload
- Remove and reinstall pulse and alsa

  > sudo dpkg --purge --force-depends pulseaudio alsa-base alsa-utils

  > sudo apt install pulseaudio alsa-base alsa-utils
- Reinstalled Firefox, then tested VLC and Spotify application, no sound on anything.
- [This question's](https://askubuntu.com/questions/955065/no-sound-on-ubuntu-windows-dual-boot) resolution says that... "This problem occurs after booting into a different OS than previously." I tried shutting down and booting Ubuntu multiple times with reboots and hard shut downs etc... all without ever booting back into Windows but to no avail.
- Updating Windows and Ubuntu's audio drivers, but none were available, the latest drivers were already installed.
- Disabled Windows Fast Startup